# fetching values with apostrophe on PLSQL

Tags: plsql

I want to get the value like this:

```
select column1, column2 from blah:

COLUMN1   COLUMN2
-----------------
value1    value2
```

I want to fetch them with apostrophe

```
COLUMN1   COLUMN2
-----------------
'value1'  'value2'
```

I need to add apostrophes to the column name but I didn't know how to do that in PLSQL

```
select '''+column1+'' from blah
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the `||` operator:

```
select '''' || column1 || '''' from blah
```

Also the `CONCAT` function can be used

Comment: Solved! Thanks Peter.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using the CHR() function to return the single-quote character given it's ASCII decimal equivalent.  Simplifies the escaping of single quotes.

```
select chr(39) || 'testing' || chr(39)
from dual;
```

In a PL/SQL program, you could even define it as a CONSTANT, then use it by that name in your code:

```
declare
  SQ        CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1) := CHR(39);         -- Single quote
  buffer    VARCHAR2(20);
begin
  select SQ || sysdate || SQ 
  into buffer
  from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
end;
```

I feel it's cleaner than 4 quotes in a row and likely easier to maintain if you have lots of columns in a single select you have to do that with.