# Dynamic sql/query: apostrophe in SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I have the problem, that there is a variable, which could contains different column names
 and then in the SELECT I want to compare the column with a specific word.
But then it seems like the apostrophe make problems:

```
query := 'SELECT value FROM table WHERE ' || variable || ' like ''word''';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query INTO rec;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN htp.p(dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
```

Comment: I see no [apostrophes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) but [quotation marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) only ?

Comment: Escaping quotes is a pain in the neck and very confusing to maintain.  See this post for another way using the CHR() function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325070/fetching-values-with-apostrophe-on-plsql/25331808#25331808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2    VAR   VARCHAR2(20);
  3    REC   NUMBER;
  4    query VARCHAR2(1000);
  5  BEGIN
  6    var   := 'TABLE_NAME';
  7    QUERY := 'SELECT count(*) FROM USER_TABLES WHERE ' || VAR || ' like ''%EMP%''';
  8    dbms_output.put_line(query);
  9    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE QUERY INTO REC;
 10    dbms_output.put_line(rec);
 11  END;
 12  /
SELECT count(*) FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%EMP%'
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**With REC as collection type :**

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      var   VARCHAR2(20);
  3      TYPE rec_typ
  4        IS TABLE OF user_tables%ROWTYPE;
  5      rec   REC_TYP;
  6      query VARCHAR2(1000);
  7  BEGIN
  8      var := 'TABLE_NAME';
  9
 10      query := 'SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES WHERE '
 11               || var
 12               || ' like ''%EMP%''';
 13
 14      dbms_output.Put_line(query);
 15
 16      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query bulk collect INTO rec;
 17
 18      FOR i IN 1..rec.count LOOP
 19          dbms_output.Put_line(Rec(i).table_name);
 20      END LOOP;
 21  END;
 22  /
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%EMP%'
EMP

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: and if the select return more then one value? how can I loop trough the variable and which type of variable should the 'rec' be?

Comment: I have added another code for REC as collection type. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for values in column that **are equal** to `word` then change `like` to `=`.
If you're searching for values in column that **contains** `word` then change `like ''word''` to `like ''%word%''` (don't forget about the third apostrophe that's closing dynamic query).

Comment: yeah the column should contain the 'word' and I just forgot to post the %'s in the question but in my code its `like ''%word%''`..with third apostrophe to close the query